# Create Telegram bot like Botfather (step-by-step)

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I've really been dragging myself from asking this question here, but after googling forever I feel It's needed. So:

I'm trying to build a bot with a similar structure as the Botfather in telegram. I'd like to enable a step by step configuration for users using my bot. So if I ask "What's your email?" I'd like them to naturally be able to answer that and I'll know what question they answered. And that's the problem, I can't seem to figure out a good structure for knowing which question they answered and what to trigger. All documentation in every bot I've scanned simply use a structure like this:

And this is not very beneficial when I don't know what the user will write or if I have duplicated accepted answers for different questions. I've tried using replies and ForceReply etc, but this also creates a weird structure and don't look as clean in the feed as natural messages.

Simply put: How do I know if a message goes together with a question and then trigger something?

Sorry for a somewhat unstructured question, hopefully one of you awesome people have an answer to my issue.

Like: http://uploadpie.com/Klj1S

Comment: As far as i know every Chat has a session so you can log every message and determine what you should send as answer.

Comment: "use a structure like this:" - looks like the structure is missing